# drum machine for traditional drum sound?

Tags: drum, machine

I'm looking for a drum machine for a traditional analog sound, i mean for rock, not for electronic music, i'd just want the basic drum sound
maybe a plugin for laptop? any suggestion is welcome!

(i own already a SR16.. which is ...ok)

Comment: Why not program tradition drum sounds into a drum machine?

Comment: how do i find them? can you do it with an SR16? otherwise which drum machien does it?

Comment: @LukeFarroh If he has insane amount of time, has a good studio, a good drummer friend and a pro about drum recording and also has a very solid sampler app... Then it is a very good idea.

Comment: @atoth It wouldn't take that much time at all. Possibly 10 minutes plus you wouldn't need a good drummer. Just someone to hit one drum at a time.

Comment: @LukeFarroh  But if he wants it to sound convincing he will need 4-5 different hits at certain velocity levels (a light snare hit is not a loud snare hit played on lower volume - sounds very different) - also he would need lots of different strokes for just hi-hat alone: open, closed, closed tight, semi-open, hit on the edge, on the bell, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Toontrack products. In particular [Superior Drummer 2.0](https://www.toontrack.com/product/superior-drummer-2/) may be of interest:

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Hansen Buur said, there are lots of good live-feel drum products out there: Toontrack, Steven Slate Drums, Native Instruments Kontakt, etc...

But it is also equally important to program the drums with a natural vibe to them, i.e. humanizing notes, accenting notes (important notes have more velocity and there could be "ghost" notes with super small velocities). For example, the "digital" drum sound is coming from having robotic performance, all notes with full velocity, on the grid exactly, sounding completely the same. (That's why I hate to listen to "Walk this way" by Run DMC - just listen to the totally even hihats - if you have a drummer playing that lifelessly, you fire them from a band).

You can use and edit pre-recorded MIDI files, those are usually the best, and you can learn a lot from them. Toontrack for sure has this as MIDI packs.

Also Misha Mansoor has a detailed tutorial about making your own drums from scratch: